# postfix SMTP outgoing gateway server, Software RAID1 vs RAID1 + RAID 0 on 2 disks

Tags: postfix, raid, performance, smtp, software-raid

I have this old smtp server that is currently running Windows 2003 and with EOL I want to move it to something that will continue to get security upgrades but at same time I want to improve performance. I am thinking about moving it to CentOS 6 with postfix.

Right now the data is stored on 2 separate drives, I am thinking of using a Software Raid.

The 2 configs I am considering is:

**1) RAID 1 and RAID 0 on 2 disks**

*Software raid allows me to place different RAID for different partitions. I am thinking RAID1 on the OS and Software and put spool in RAID0. This would speed up my spool while offer reliability on OS and software.*

**2) RAID 1 only**

*I lose out on write performance but get better read performance for my statistics and queue monitoring.*

---

This server is 2.8ghz Xeon with SCSI drives(not SAS) and 4gb ram (getting a new servers is NOT an option)

I would prefer to go with Option 1, is there anything I should be concerned about? What happens if my RAID0 fails or gets corrupted? Will postfix send corrupted emails or just fail? How reliably can the system detect RAID0 failure?

RAID0 also allows to set custom stripping from what I understand. Since I know the general file size of my emails, can I control that each file takes up an individual block so that in case of failure I would only lose half my spool?

Any other issues I should be worried about?

or would the performance improvement be minimal and I should just go with Option 2, RAID1 only?

Again, this is an SMTP OUTGOING gateway, it will not store any important data. The RAID1 simply exists for insuring the PC does not crash and minimize downtime.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend option 2 for just RAID 1 only. It's not really worth it to complicate your setup and double your chance of failure. Probably your best bet for improved performance would be to improve the rest of your hardware (though not an option you say). If your RAID0 fails, it will almost certainly just fail and not work at all. I can't really say what postfix will do in that situation, but surely it will error and stop functioning.

> "RAID0 also allows to set custom stripping from what I understand.
>   Since I know the general file size of my emails, can I control that
>   each file takes up an individual block so that in case of failure I
>   would only lose half my spool?"

RAID0 requires all members to function to be able to use it at all. If one disk goes down, your OS and software on the RAID1 will still function, but anything requiring the RAID0 will not. You will lose your entire spool. RAID also knows nothing about your email files or the file system so there may still be parts of emails and some full emails on the remaining disk in raw data, but recovering them will be very very difficult and isn't really feasible. They won't be stored so that a file starts at the beginning of a block. The blocks are just how the data is sectioned and distributed. So it's good this data wouldn't be needed. The remaining disk (as part of the RAID0) certainly won't be usable until the configuration is reworked.